# Fix Laravel scope warnings of phpstan (or larastan)?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

How to deal with scopes in Laravel when analyzing code with phpstan/larastan?

I'm getting this error:

```
Call to an undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::active().
```

Do I need to typehint it somehow?

I'm trying to avoid `@phpstan-ignore-next-line`

It's worth mentioning that said error only appears when I'm using a scope inside scope.
In other cases, `LaraStan` is preventing `PhpStan` warnings successfully.

Comment: You could put such errors into ignore list within your config file (https://phpstan.org/user-guide/ignoring-errors#ignoring-in-configuration-file)

Comment: I'm thinking about creating a new class that would extend the Eloquent\Builder for each Model, but I'm not sure how to implement it yet

Comment: Issues around "`using a scope inside scope`" or around "`chaining a scope after another scope`" can be fixed by doc-commenting; see my answer's edit.

Answer (score 6):

At time of writting, there are three approaches.

But I use both first and third approach in the same project, because there are many Composer packages which don't use my second or third approach.

### First approach is a workaround

Simply ignore Laravel's "magic" in `phpstan.neon` file, like:

```
parameters:
    paths:
        - app

    excludePaths:
        - ./vendor/**

    reportUnmatchedIgnoredErrors: false
    ignoreErrors:
        - '#Call to an undefined method#'
        - '#Call to an undefined static method#'
```

### Notes

You can customize above Regular-expression(s) to ignore only what's needed.

**But** PHP does not allow a class to have same name twice:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare App\Models\MyModel::active()
```

**While** Laravel's scope "magic" allows the same name from both "static" and "instance" context, like:

```
$query = MyModel::active();
$query = MyModel::where('id', '!=', 1)->active();
```

**Meaning**, even if you use doc-comment, like:

```
/**
 * @method static active()
 * @method active()
 */
class MyModel { ... }
```

It only changes `phpstan`'s message, to something like:

```
Static call to instance method App\Models\MyModel::active().
```

### Second approach is a solution

For reasons mentioned in above note-section;
Prefix all uses of Laravel's "static scope magic" with "query()->", like change from:

```
MyModel::active();
```

Into:

```
MyModel::query()->active();
```

Finally, add doc-comment(s), like:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @method Builder|static active()
 * @method static Builder|static query()
 */
class MyModel extends Model { ... }
```

### Third approach is a trick

Basically, do everything that second approach says,
**But** instead of doc-comment(s), like most libraries, pair the scope-method with a normal-method which checks the same field(s) without any query, like:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @method static Builder|static query()
 */
class MyModel extends Model {

    /**
     * @return bool|Builder|static
     */
    public function active()
    {
        return $this->status == 'active';
    }

    public function scopeActive(Builder $query): void
    {
        /** @var Builder|static $query */
        $query->where('status', '=', 'active');

        // NOTE: above `@var` is only required to chain other scope(s).
    }

}
```

> **Note** that above tricks both IDE and `phpstan` into thinking that `->active()` *may* return `Builder|static`, which allows chaining, like:
>
> ```
> $query = MyModel::query()
>     ->active()
>     ->where(...);
> ```

Comment: I think PHPstan have exposed the major flaw in Laravel design, because laravel puts scopes in the Model, which is obviously a mistake, because scopes related to the Query Builder. Thus, I believe the description of scopes should be removed from the Model and there must be a Query Builder class for each model separately. I'm thinking of override a ->query() function to make it return a model specific builder... So basically I don't think we need to fight PhpStan, but rather we need to fight Laravel